# Silverlight Drag and drop custom controls

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

I want to create a drag and drop functionality in my silverlight 3.0 project.

I use Nov 2009 release of the silverlight toolkit.

I created several custom user controls and want to apply drag and drop functionality to them.

I checked using

> ListBoxDragDropTarget

with a **ListBox** but found that it must be bound to some data source.

is there a way to put my custom controls inside the list box and achieve the drag-drop behaviour ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit your control from DragDropTarget. Let say you want to create TextBox and you want to drop items from DataGrid. Then you create

```
public class DropingTextBox : DragDropTarget<DataGridRow,TextBox>{}
```

Then you can override methods of DragDropTarget.

Please write what you want to do so maybe I can help more. What behaviour you want to acheive?

Comment: Thanks Damir, I want to create some chart controls, data grid controls and place them in regions where I can drag and drop controls between regions. I will try you solution and tell you what happened